# Projectile in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm attempting to learn Unity (so please forgive my newbie-ness). I've set up my project as 2d, got a sprite moving about and I'm trying to get a projectile firing (I appreciate there are MANY SO q's about such, but I just can't get it to work, after trying many solutions). I'm a complete nub when it comes to physics!

Here's my very simple script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform mObject;
    public Transform mProjectile;
    public Vector2 mProjectileSpeed = new Vector2 (10f, 10f);
    public Vector2 mSpeed = new Vector2(15, 15);
    private Vector2 mMovement;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float inputX = Input.GetAxis("X");
        float inputY = Input.GetAxis("Y");

        mMovement = new Vector2 (mSpeed.x * inputX, mSpeed.y * inputY);

        if (Input.GetButton ("Fire1"))
            Shoot ();
    }

    void Shoot(){
        GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate (mProjectile, rigidbody2D.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        clone.rigidbody2D.velocity = (clone.transform.forward * 1000);
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        rigidbody2D.velocity = mMovement;
    }
}
```

And this is what it's doing:

[image: Oddity]

No force is being added to the instantiated object and it shoots out both sides of my sprite, which I just don't understand at all.

I did find a solution on the Unity answers site that said to `IgnoreCollider` just in case the two box colliders were conflicting results, but it didn't make a difference.

I'm sure I'm doing something completely stupid, but how can I do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: You pass a `direction` into your `Shoot` method, but then you don't use it. Is this intended?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Thats a remnant of a previous solution that didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried instantiating projectiles in front of the sprite? It can be done by setting the instantiate position with an offset: `rigidbody2D.transform.position + clone.transform.forward * 10.0f`. Seems like the sprite and the projectiles are colliding.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately it made little difference :(

Comment: To locate problem, disable all colliders in your scene, especially player's and projectile prefab's colliders. Then, enable them in different combinations. Only then we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Addforce() method, 
something like this :

```
gameObj.rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector3.up * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
```

or

```
gameObj.rigidbody2D.AddForce(transform.forward * 100);
```

or

```
gameObj.rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector3.up * 1000);
```

See which combination and what values matches your requirement and use accordingly. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As @maZZZu said, Instantiate your projectile sprites ahead of your character so that your character and projectiles may not collide.

Secondly, `clone.rigidbody2D.velocity = (clone.transform.forward * 1000);` part of your code will only allow the projectile to move in forward direction (x-axis in case to 2D and z-axis in 3D). Try using mMovement instead (if you want it to move in other directions as well). e.g. `clone.rigidbody2D.velocity = (mMovement * 1000);`

Comment: Please don't use signatures or taglines in your posts.